# PHP curl not working well as browser does

Tags: php, curl

I write a curl request in PHP for getting data from a Chinese site.

I made a simple C# application , it works well as expected.

Also I made my request via Firefox or Chrome and they work well.

Working well means that 800 data received.

But in PHP and Cpanel, it's not working well.

I mean that i receive just single data.

How can i debug where the problem is?

```
$url = "http://search.ickey.cn/site/getsup?keyword=" . $query."&t=".array_sum( explode( ' ' , microtime() ) ) ;
$curl_options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate',
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=> TRUE,
CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>TRUE,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://search.ickey.cn/"
);                            
$ch = curl_init();               
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curl_options );            
$jsonresponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

for test:
http://search.ickey.cn/site/getsup?keyword=3305&num=2000&t=1495644392

compare response in Chrome and in Php

Comment: how can we debug the problem? do you have any code for us?

Comment: @Edwin you're right, i added the code.

Comment: 1 obvious error, you're not url-encoding $query (see urlencode())

Comment: @hanshenrik urlencode doesn't change anything
test this: http://search.ickey.cn/site/getsup?keyword=3305&num=2000&t=1495644392

Comment: "I mean that i receive just single data." I don't know what that means, can you clarify?

Comment: @Goose just test that

http://search.ickey.cn/site/getsup?keyword=3305

compare response in Chrome and in Php
in Chrome there are 800 json data but in PHP there is 1 json data

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I have wated 12 hour and come to a solution. Make sure you have no space for any variables or in url. Like "$user_name = "Lokman Hosen"". You have to give urldecode "$user_name = "Lokman_Hosen"" or "$user_name = "Lokman%20Hosen"". You can use

```
urldecode()
```

Function to remove spac. Now cURL dont allow any space. Your browser works because when you paste url in browser and hit enter then browser remove space by onother character.